# Switching from local database to SQL server

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

So our current code loaded a csv file into a local jdbcTemplate in which then I do some querying. The issue was always performance, and we finally got access to a SQL server that could load the data. Naturally the company gets the guy with basically no database skills to set this up :P

```
    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

     @RequestMapping("/queryService")
        public void queryService(@RequestParam("id")String id)
    {
    log.info("Creating tables");

            jdbcTemplate.execute("DROP TABLE accounts IF EXISTS");
            jdbcTemplate.execute("CREATE TABLE accounts(id VARCHAR(255), name VARCHAR(255), Organization__c VARCHAR(255)";

     insertBatch(accounts,dataSource);
     ArrayList<Account2> filteredaccs = filterAccount(jdbcTemplate);
```

.

```
        public void insertBatch(ArrayList<Account2> accs, DataSource dataSource) {
    List<Map<String, Object>> batchValues = new ArrayList<>(accs.size());
            for (Account2 a : accs) {
                Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                map.put("id", a.getId());
                map.put("name", a.getName());
                map.put("Organization__c", a.getOrganization__c());
                batchValues.add(map);
    }
    SimpleJdbcInsert simpleJdbcInsert = new SimpleJdbcInsert(dataSource).withTableName("accounts");

            int[] ints = simpleJdbcInsert.executeBatch(batchValues.toArray(new Map[accs.size()]));


}
```

.

```
public ArrayList<Account2> filterAccount(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate)
{
 String sql= "query string";
ArrayList<Account2> searchresults = (ArrayList<Account2>) jdbcTemplate.query(sql,
                    new RowMapperResultSetExtractor<Account2>(new AccountRowMapper(), 130000));
return searchresults;
}
```

.

```
public class AccountRowMapper implements RowMapper<Account2> {
        public Account2 mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            Account2 a = new Account2();
            a.setId(rs.getString("id"));
            a.setName(rs.getString("name"));
            a.setOrganization__c(rs.getString("Organization__c"));
return a;
}
}
```

The question here is what is the quickest way for me to 'switch' over to using a SQL server to pull the data down, with the same table and rows, without changing too much of my current code?

Comment: You're probably going to have to change the data-access code if you want to see any performance improvements.  On the plus side, this SHOULD be relatively isolated from the rest of your code.  Also, make sure your schema is reasonable.  Should `id` really be a `varchar(255)` and not an `int`?

Comment: id could have letters too. the issue was maintaining the data. currently i pull down a large csv daily which takes a while, and really just need to query it once when i run my code. If i can query it from an actual server that is updated more frequently, it should net more more performance and less likely to encounter heapspace issues.